# Why does Doctrine try to duplicate a Many-To-Many relationship even though I check if it exists beforehand? And why does it randomly crash on flush?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, many-to-many, undefined-index

I'm having a really hard time with Doctrine failing to work as expected.

**What my code tries to do.**

I'm writing a CLI command in my Symfony 3 web application that is supposed to tidy up a tags table in my database. There are Actors and there are Tags. There's a Many-To-Many relation between Actors and Tags (bidirectional). My command imports a CSV file where in one column current Tags are listed, and in another column there are some substitutes for them. It goes through the file, line by line, finds the existing Tag, reads all its current relations to Actors, deletes the Tag, creates a new Tag (substitute) or uses an existing one, and attaches to it all the Actor relations of the deleted one.

**The code (its crucial part)**

```
protected function doReplace(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output, $input_file)
{
    $em = $this->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getManager();
    $con = $em->getConnection();

    //open the input CSV
    $input_fhndl = fopen($input_file, 'r');
    if (!$input_fhndl)
        throw new \Exception('Unable to open file!');

    //do everything in a big transaction, so that if anything fails
    //everything rolls back and there's no half-finished information
    //in the DB
    $con->beginTransaction();
    try
    {
        //I was trying to use official Doctrine recommendation for batch inserts
        //to clear the entity manager after a bunch of operations, 
        //but it does neither help nor make things worse
//      $batchSize = 20;
        $i = 0;
        //reading the file line by line
        while (($line = fgetcsv($input_fhndl)) !== false) 
        {
            //$line[0] - source tag ID (the one to be substituted)
            //$line[1] - source tag type ('language' or 'skill')
            //$line[2] - source tag value (e.g. 'pole dancing (advanced)')
            //$line[3] - replacement tag value (e.g. 'pole dancing')

            $i++;

            if ($i === 1) //omit table headers
                continue;

            $line[3] = trim($line[3]);
            if ($line[3] === null || $line[3] === '') //omit lines with no replacements
                continue;

            //getting the tag to be replaced
            $src_tag = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Tag')
                ->find($line[0]);
            if (!$src_tag)
            {
                //if the tag that is supposed to be replaced doesn't exist, just skip it
                continue;
            }


            $replacement_tag = null;
            $skip = false;

            //if the replacement value is '!' they just want to delete the original
            //tag without replacing it
            if (trim($line[3]) === '!')
            {
                $output->writeln('Removing '.$line[2].' ');
            }
            //here comes the proper replacement
            else
            {
                //there can be a few replacement values for one source tag
                //in such case they're separated with | in the input file
                $replacements = explode('|', $line[3]);

                foreach ($replacements as $replacement)
                {
                    $skip = false;
                    $output->write('Replacing '.$line[2].' with '.trim($replacement).'. ');

                    //getOrCreateTag looks for a tag with the same type and value as the replacement
                    //if it finds one, it retrieves the entity, if it doesn't it creates a new one
                    $replacement_tag = $this->getOrCreateTag($em, $src_tag->getTagType(), trim($replacement), $output);
                    if ($replacement_tag === $src_tag) //delete the original tag only if it is different from the replacement
                    {
                        $skip = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //we iterate through deleted Tag's relationships with Actors
                        foreach ($src_tag->getActors() as $actor)
                        {
                            //this part used to be the many-to-many fail point but i managed to fix it by removing indexBy: id line from Actor->Tag relation definition
                            if (!$replacement_tag->getActors() || !$replacement_tag->getActors()->contains($actor))
                                $replacement_tag->addActor ($actor);
                        }
                        $em->persist($replacement_tag);
                        //...and if I uncomment this flush()
                        //I get errors like Notice: Undefined index: 000000005f12fa20000000000088a5f2
                        //from Doctrine internals
                        //even though it should be harmless
//                      $em->flush();
                    }
                }
            }

            if (!$skip) //delete the original tag only if it is different from the replacement
            {
                $em->remove($src_tag);
                $em->flush(); //this flush both deletes the original tag and sets up the new one
                //with its relations
            }

//          if (($i % $batchSize) === 0) {
//              $em->flush(); // Executes all updates.
//              $em->clear(); // Detaches all objects from Doctrine!
//          }
        }
        $em->flush(); //one final flush just in case
        $con->commit();
    }
    catch (\Exception $e)
    {
        $output->writeln('<error> Something went wrong! Rolling back... </error>');
        $con->rollback();
        throw $e;
    }

    //closing the input file
    fclose($input_fhndl);
}

protected function getOrCreateTag($em, $tag_type, $value, $output)
{
    $value = trim($value);

    $replacement_tag = $em
        ->createQuery('SELECT t FROM AppBundle:Tag t WHERE t.tagType = :tagType AND t.value = :value')
        ->setParameter('tagType', $tag_type)
        ->setParameter('value', $value)
        ->getOneOrNullResult();

    if (!$replacement_tag)
    {
        $replacement_tag = new Tag();
        $replacement_tag->setTagType($tag_type);
        $replacement_tag->setValue($value);
        $output->writeln('Creating new.');
    }
    else
    {
        $output->writeln('Using existing.');
    }

    return $replacement_tag;
}
```

**How it fails**

<strike>Even though i do this check: `$replacement_tag->getActors()->contains($actor)` Doctrine tries to create a duplicate Actor-Tag relation:</strike>

```
[Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\UniqueConstraintViolationException]
An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO actor_tags (actor_id, tag_id) VALUES (?, ?)' with params [280, 708]:
SQLSTATE[23505]: Unique violation: 7 ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "actor_tags_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (actor_id, tag_id)=(280, 708) already exists.
```

I managed to fix the above by removing `indexBy: id` from Actor->Tag relation definition (it was there by accident).

<strike>And additionally, when I do some theoretically harmless modifications, like uncommenting the commented `flush()` call or not using the big transaction, I get this</strike>

Still even without any modifications to the code, at some point of importing I get this:

```
  [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException]
  Notice: Undefined index: 000000001091cbbe000000000b4818c6


Exception trace:
 () at /src/__sources/atm/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php:2907
 Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork->getEntityIdentifier() at /src/__sources/atm/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Persisters/Collection/ManyToManyPersister.php:543
 Doctrine\ORM\Persisters\Collection\ManyToManyPersister->collectJoinTableColumnParameters() at /src/__sources/atm/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Persisters/Collection/ManyToManyPersister.php:473
 Doctrine\ORM\Persisters\Collection\ManyToManyPersister->getDeleteRowSQLParameters() at /src/__sources/atm/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Persisters/Collection/ManyToManyPersister.php:77
 Doctrine\ORM\Persisters\Collection\ManyToManyPersister->update() at /src/__sources/atm/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php:388
 Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork->commit() at /src/__sources/atm/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityManager.php:359
 Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager->flush() at /src/__sources/atm/src/AppBundle/Command/AtmReplaceTagsCommand.php:176
 AppBundle\Command\AtmReplaceTagsCommand->doReplace() at /src/__sources/atm/src/AppBundle/Command/AtmReplaceTagsCommand.php:60
 AppBundle\Command\AtmReplaceTagsCommand->execute() at /src/__sources/atm/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/Command.php:262
 Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at /src/__sources/atm/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:848
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at /src/__sources/atm/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:190
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at /src/__sources/atm/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Console/Application.php:80
 Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application->doRun() at /src/__sources/atm/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:121
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at /src/__sources/atm/bin/console:28
```

Doing `$em->clear()` every few rows doesn't help.

**What I tried**

- I tried changing the `flush()` call sequence which often resulted in that weird undefined index error.
- I tried commenting out the big transaction (to no avail).
- I tried to call `$em->clear()` after each 20 records - that also didn't change anything at all.

I will really appreciate any help with this.

**Additional info**

YAML definition of Actor->Tag relation (for Actor entity):

```
 manyToMany:
    tags:
      targetEntity: AppBundle\Entity\Tag
      inversedBy: actors
      #indexBy: id
#the above line caused the Many-To-Many duplicate problem - commenting it out fixed that part of the problem.
      joinTable:
        name: actor_tags
        joinColumns:
          actor_id:
            referencedColumnName: id
        inverseJoinColumns:
          tag_id:
            referencedColumnName: id
```

YAML definition of Tag->Actor relation (for Tag entity):

```
  manyToMany:
    actors:
      targetEntity: AppBundle\Entity\Actor
      mappedBy: tags
```

`Tag::addActor()` function definition

```
public function addActor(\AppBundle\Entity\Actor $actor)
{
    $this->actor[] = $actor;
    $actor->addTag($this);

    return $this;
}
```

`Actor::addTag()` function definition

```
public function addTag(\AppBundle\Entity\Tag $tag)
{
    $this->tags[] = $tag;

    $this->serializeTagIds();

    return $this;
}
```

If you need any additional info just ask. Thank you very much.

Comment: So I partially managed to fix the problem. I no longer get Many-To-Many duplicate relations, after I removed the `indexBy: id` line from the Actor->Tag relation definition. But I'm still getting the `undefined index` errors, no matter what I do :-(

Comment: Similar problem here, commenting $em->clear() kind of solve the problem. Still searching for a better solution.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in your `Tag::addActor()` and `Actor::addTag()` functions. -- They are calling each other recursively without checking what's in their collections before adding a new entry, which is why you're getting a duplicate insert.

Change your functions so that the `ArrayCollection` instance is checked first as follows:

```
public function addActor(\AppBundle\Entity\Actor $actor)
{
    if (!$this->actor->contains($actor)) {
        $this->actor->add($actor);
    }

    $actor->addTag($this);

    return $this;
}

public function addTag(\AppBundle\Entity\Tag $tag)
{
    if (!$this->tags->contains($tag)) {
        $this->tags->add($tag);
    }

    $this->serializeTagIds();

    return $this;
}
```

In addition to this I assume the constructor functions for both entities initialise the properties as a new `ArrayCollection` instance, otherwise you'll get a "trying to call add() on null" error. I also assume you've got `use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;` at the top of these classes.

For the Tag class:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->actor = new ArrayCollection();
}
```

For the Actor class:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->tags = new ArrayCollection();
}
```

*These will **not** overwrite/wipe the relationships when an existing entity is loaded. It simply ensures that new entities have an `ArrayCollection` instance set up correctly before you try adding elements to it.*

**Crucial point: Your YAML definition uses property name "actors" but your class functions refer to `$this->actor`. Should that not be `$this->actors`?** If this is true adjust the above examples to use `$this->actors` instead of `$this->actor`.

Finally **do not use `$em->clear()` in this case**. That will cause all objects the entity manager knows about to become in an unmanaged state, meaning they wouldn't persist any further changes in your functions until you `$em->merge()` them again.

Comment: Thanks for the reply man! It's been a long time since had a chance to work with Doctrine but I will surely test your solution at some point.